# Range (list) as dummy columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns with start and end range. I want make dummy columns for range between this columns. I can make it by apply method, but it is very slow. Can I make it without apply (because I have ~2-5M rows).

Entire DataFrame:

```
    start     end
0   36        36
1   31        31
2   29        29
3   10        10
4   35        35
5   42        44
6   24        26
```

What I want to see:

```
    start   end 8   9   10  24  25  26  29  31  35  36  42  43  44
0   36      36  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN
1   31      31  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   29      29  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   10      10  NaN NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   35      35  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
5   42      44  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0 1.0 1.0
6   24      26  NaN NaN NaN 1.0 1.0 1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7   25      25  NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
8   35      35  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN
9   8       10  1.0 1.0 1.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Now I use this code:

```
import itertools

def zip_with_scalar(l, o):
    return dict(zip(l, itertools.repeat(o)))
df.merge(df.apply(lambda s: pd.Series(zip_with_scalar(range(s['start'], s['end']+1), 1)), axis = 1), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
a = [dict.fromkeys(range(x, y), 1) for x, y in zip(df['start'], df['end']+1)]
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(a, index=df.index))
print (df)
   start  end   10   24   25   26   29   31   35   36   42   43   44
0     36   36  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1     31   31  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2     29   29  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3     10   10  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4     35   35  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5     42   44  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
6     24   26  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

**Performance**:

```
#[70000 rows x 2 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

def a(df):
    a = [dict.fromkeys(range(x, y), 1) for x, y in zip(df['start'], df['end']+1)]
    return df.join(pd.DataFrame(a, index=df.index))

import itertools

def zip_with_scalar(l, o):
    return dict(zip(l, itertools.repeat(o)))
def b(df):
    return df.merge(df.apply(lambda s: pd.Series(zip_with_scalar(range(s['start'], s['end']+1), 1)), axis = 1), left_index=True, right_index=True)


In [176]: %timeit a(df.copy())
202 ms ± 6.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [177]: %timeit b(df.copy())
38.9 s ± 1.19 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```